# Why does IXMLDOMDocument2->get_documentElement give me IXMLDOMElement * with a refcount set to 2?

Tags: com, smart-pointers, atl, msxml, msxml6

I can't understand why a Smart Pointer seems to be created with an initial Ref Count set to two (2), with no apparent memory leaks afterward.

MRE:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <MsXml2.h>
#include <atlcomcli.h>

int main() {

    bool bCoIntOk = false;
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx( nullptr, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED );
    if ( hr == S_OK ) {
        bCoIntOk = true;
        CComPtr<IXMLDOMDocument2> spIXMLDOMDocument2;
        hr = spIXMLDOMDocument2.CoCreateInstance( L"Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0",
                                                  nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER );
        if ( hr == S_OK ) {
            VARIANT_BOOL vbSuccess = VARIANT_FALSE;
            hr = spIXMLDOMDocument2->loadXML( CComBSTR( L"<root/>" ), &vbSuccess );
            if ( hr == S_OK && vbSuccess == VARIANT_TRUE ) {
                CComPtr<IXMLDOMElement> spIXMLDOMElement;
                hr = spIXMLDOMDocument2->get_documentElement( &spIXMLDOMElement );
                if ( hr == S_OK ) {
                    spIXMLDOMDocument2.Release();
                    spIXMLDOMElement.p->AddRef();
                    ULONG ulRefCount = spIXMLDOMElement.p->Release();
                    printf( "IXMLDOMElement RefCount is %u\n", ulRefCount );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if ( bCoIntOk ) CoUninitialize();

}
```

Output result:

> IXMLDOMElement RefCount is 2

I thought that an Interface pointer would have a "Ref Count" set to one (1) just before the last "release", in order to avoid memory leaks.
Fact is that if I put the above code in some "while ( true )" infinite loop, there is no apparent memory leaks.

Question: What is wrong with my code and/or my understanding?

Comment: You own one reference. The document object owns the other. The document element existed before `get_documentElement` call, and will continue to exist after `spIXMLDOMElement` goes out of scope and releases its reference.

Comment: CComPtr<> does no reference counting by itself, that's the job of the invisible code that implements IXMLDOMElement.  You have decent evidence that it caches elements by itself, possibly when loadXML() loads the document.  Or possibly lazily, later when you start accessing the document.  Not knowing the exact answer is the feature, not a bug.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I updated my code, adding a Release on the document before querying the RefCount. Nothing changes, still 2 for the IXMLDOMElement...

Comment: AddRef and Release values have no strict meaning beyond 0 and N (N > 0). Official doc indeed stipulates "This value is intended to be used only for test purposes."

Comment: @SimonMourier I always thought that "test purposes" was "checking before your last Release to see if some other Release is missing in your code"

Comment: There's likely a reference from the element back to the document, to keep it alive while the element is being referenced externally. For all it knows, you are about to call `get_ownerDocument` on it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes, and if I do call `get_ownerDocument` after the Release on IXMLDOMDocument2, it works. I have would have thought that the Ref Counting would be the other way around: 2 for the document, and one for the Element, then... But after `get_documentElement`, the Document is still at one...

Comment: There's likely an internal, non-COM reference from the element back to the document. They can't both `AddRef` each other, or else they'd never get destroyed due to a circular dependency. Nothing says that a single reference count, managed by `AddRef` and `Release`, must be the sole means by which an object manages its lifetime.